# getpriority() function in linux

Tags: linux-kernel

may i know the exact usage of getpriority() call used in linux.. even after searching thru net, i couldnt understand it exactly.. can someone explain it with an example.. thnx in advance :)

Comment: Please tell us what you don't understand from the man page.

Comment: @bmargulies:  FYI.. am newbie for the linux kernel.. please tolerate with my silly questions.. The man page tells, "The getpriority() call returns the highest priority (lowest numerical value) enjoyed by any of the specified processes".. so does it mean, it always returns -20? ( the highest priority of any process in linux? moreover i dont understand the parameters..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   The  scheduling  priority  of  the  process, process group, or user, as
   indicated by which and who is obtained with the  getpriority  call ...
```

So, it returns a priority. It takes two args.

The first arg tells it how to interpret the second arg.

```
   which is ... one  of  PRIO_PROCESS,
   PRIO_PGRP, or PRIO_USER,
```

So, if which is PRIO_PROCESS, then 'who' is a process id, if it is PRIO_PGRP, it is a 
process group id, and if it is PRIO_USER, it is a user ID. A zero of who means the caller.

In the second two cases, the result is to select a set of processes, so it returns the lowest priority number of all of the selected processes.

Comment: @bmargulies: thnx a lot.. so, i understand "getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0) returns the nice value (static priority assigned to the process by the kernel) of the process, from which the above fn is invoked..

Comment: @inquisitive Yup, that's my belief.